# How to compile WebAssembly from multiple cpp files?

Tags: c++, web, compilation, webassembly

I'm using emscripten to compile c++ to WASM, but can only do this for one file at a time. I don't want to put my entire project and libraries in one file, but I haven't found any information on how to properly compile it.

Comment: Research build systems. Read up on linking multiple object files / compilation units into one library or executable.

Answer (score 5):

Just put all source files in the emcc command line like this:

```
emcc src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp
```

See reference here: https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/tools_reference/emcc.html

Comment: How would you go about doing it if they are already separate SIDE_MODULE wasm files?